# Using split in Java String

Tags: java, string, split

I need to split a String with **dot '.'** but with one catch as explained below For example, if a String is like this

```
   String str = "A.B.C"
```

then, splitting with dot, will give `A,B and C`.

But if the some part is marked with single inverted comma, then split should ignore it

```
String str = "A.B.'C.D'"
```

then, splitting with dot, should give `A,B and C.D`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If the String is always in the given format, you could try : `\\.(?![A-Za-z]')` as regex

[demo here](http://regex101.com/r/mH4wJ4/1)

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks like its matched the dots.

Comment: @Doomsknight - It splits on what it selects / consumes (not what it matches). It consumes only the literal "." the *negative-look ahead* is just *matched*, not consumed.:)

Comment: Oops, im getting mixed up with Match. +1 for a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

First, split at `'` and afterwards, if any of the split results end in `.`, split at `.` as well again.

```
"A.B.'C.D'"
=>
"A.B.", "C.D"
=> "A", "B", "C.D"
```

## Java 8 Example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String str = "A.B.'C.D'";
    final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String singleQuoteSplitResultArrayElement : str.split("'")) {
        if (singleQuoteSplitResultArrayElement.endsWith(".")) {
            Collections.addAll(result, singleQuoteSplitResultArrayElement.split("\\."));
        } else {
            result.add(singleQuoteSplitResultArrayElement);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(result.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is as follows - will work with single letter and multiple letter tokens:

```
String input = "A.B.'C.D'";
//                                              | not following capital letter(s) and '
//                                              |           | dot (escaped)
//                                              |           |  | not followed by 
//                                              |           |  | capital letter(s) and '
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input.split("(?<![A-Z]+?')\\.(?![A-Z]+?')")));
```

**Output**

```
[A, B, 'C.D']
```

**Note**

If you want it case-insensitive, prepend `(?i)` to the `Pattern`: `(?i)(?<![A-Z]+?')\\.(?![A-Z]+?')")`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a method in the standard library that does this. It is not too difficult to write yourself, though:

```
public static String[] splitByDots(String s)
{
    List<String> ss = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean inString = false;
    int start = 0;

    for (int p = 0; p < s.length(); p++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(p);
        if (ch == '\'') {
            inString = !inString;
        }
        else if (ch == '.') { 
            if (!inString) {
                ss.add(s.substring(start, p));
                start = p + 1;
            }
        }
    }

    ss.add(s.substring(start));
    return ss.toArray(new String[ss.size()]);
}
```

If you want to trim whitespace or remove the quote characters, you will have to tweak the above code a bit, but otherwise it does what you asked for.